# How to make java interface / abstract class that uses per-field equals instead of default equals?

Tags: java, hash, equals

I have a process which requires creating java classes which will serve as keys in a table (as a key in a Spark framework). To get the correct functionality, I need to override the default object equals() and hash code methods with functions that perform field-wise comparison. (I generate this automatically in Eclipse/Intellij).

The problem is that each time I create a new class or make a change to the existing class - I need to re-generate the equals/hash. This is a buggy process, since if I forget to regenerate the equals there is no compile error.

Is there any way in Java to create classes which have as default a field-wise equals/hash code?

Comment: You might be able to hack something together with reflection, but in general you should stick with something that's easy to read and maintain. Just put a post-it note on your monitor so you remember to recreate the equals() and hashcode() functions.

Comment: I'd rather keep my monitor for code :)

Comment: In Intellij IDEA 14.1, you can create your own templates for equals/hashcode. Then, when you generate the equals method, you select your own template instead of the default. However, I assume you're asking if you can remove the auto-generation step altogether? I don't think so, but you could perhaps introduce static analysis tools that check you have generated the correct methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such feature is provided by [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html) project. It includes annotation processor which is executed during compilation. It's compatible with Eclipse, maven, ant and so on. You should just annotate your class with `@EqualsAndHashCode` and it will automatically create the equals and hashCode for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement such a check in a "generic" way ... using reflection. Meaning: use reflection to automatically fetch all fields of objects; and compare each of them.

But of course, using reflection like that is probably a great way to kill your performance.

Thus a more "serious" answer is: consider how exactly your "process which requires creating java classes" works. Maybe you can replace the "manual creation of new Java classes" with an automated step. Meaning: do not write Java classes yourself. Instead; built a generator that creates these classes for you (including equals and hashCode).

Or, third and again less serious option: use Scala for these classes. When creating "case classes"; the Scala compiler takes care of equals, hashCode, ... you name it.